# How do I keep a running count in Google Sheets with skipped lines?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, array-formulas, counting, cumulative-sum

I have a Google Sheet that looks like this:

```
A           |
Group 1     |
Lorem       |
Ipsum       |
Dolor       |
null        |
Group 2     |
Sit         |
Amet        | 
Consectetur |
```

I would like to create a new column (preferably in column A) that keeps a **running count** of entries, skipping the blank rows ("null"), and skipping the Group headers.

```
A     | B
null  | Group 1 
1     | Lorem 
2     | Ipsum 
3     | Dolor 
null  | null   
null  | Group 2 
4     | Sit 
5     | Amet  
6     | Consectetur
```

If an entry is added or deleted, then the desired output would automatically update the numbering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF((B:B="")+(REGEXMATCH(B:B, "Group")),,
 MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B:B)))*
              IF((B:B="")+(REGEXMATCH(B:B, "Group")),,1)), 
         SIGN(IF((B:B="")+(REGEXMATCH(B:B, "Group")),,1)))))
```

[image: 0]